# Disable GoogleMaps v2 View so that it ignores all touch events

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Although I call `setEnabled(false)` on the map's view, touch events still occur. In my case I set up a marker and an info window and I don't want the user to close the info window. Unfortunately by touching the map the info window still disappears.

```
mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getView().setEnabled(false);
```

I already do

```
mapFragment.getMap().getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false)
```

but this doesn't prevent touches from closing the info window.

Comment: Filed as a bug: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5114

Answer (score 0):

What about setting listeners on `GoogleMap` with `setOnMapClickListener`, `setOnInfoWindowClickListener` and `setOnMarkerClickListener` to consume the events, i.e. do-nothing?

Comment: You don't provide an answer, that is a question. Verify it before submitting it or provide it as a comment to the question instead.